# Are respirators a better option to prevent infection?

Tags: virus, zoonotic-viruses

Are respirators a better alternative to surgical or n95 masks when it comes to preventing infection by the 2019 ncov virus?
[image]

Comment: N95 can apply to respirators too - it just means that the filter (or mask) prevents 95% of particles smaller than 3 microns.

Comment: As @Chris notes, there are several types of respirators. It's also [currently unknown](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/about/transmission.html) exactly how person-to-person transmission of novel coronavirus occurs, so masks may be entirely  irrelevant. I'm afraid your question lacks adequate prior research.